# opening var/www with windows from ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2

I have apache2 installed on a ubuntu12.04 workstation and in the var/www folder is an index.html. Now I am connected with a win7 workstation via hotspot to ubuntu. I can ping from one to the other and I can connect to the internet from win7 via ubuntu.
How can I open the website in var/www from win7?
What is the best way to get access to apache2 from other devices like smartphones?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it as

```
  hostname:hostport/pathtohtmlpage
```

but you need to set enough permissions.

Comment: I try : 10.42.0.1:80/index.html , permission for index.html is 755. Its the first time I try this, so apache is all default settings.

Comment: fine what did get ?

Comment: timeout, no connection. In another post NlightNfotis writes about ps -A | grep 'httpd' to test if apache is running. I get no return entering this command, so maybe apache isnt running? but I can go on localhost/ on the ubuntu machine.

Comment: try all the possibilities . every thing is worth a try.